# How can I send an email with a zip file attached in Python?

Tags: python, email, zip

I have a zip folder named `csv` in my directory here:

- /home/local/user/project/zip_module/csv

I would like to send an email with this zip folder as an attachment.

Until now I have sent emails from Python by using the `smtplib` 
module, but I don't know how to send an email with a zip folder as an attachment.

I have searched on Google, but the code I’ve found is for compressing and sending an email, not attaching a zip to file to an email.

Answer (score 3):

Say the zip file you wish to attach is `'/home/local/user/project/zip_module/csv.zip'`,
and `to`, `sender`, `subject` and `text` contain your to address, from address, the subject and mail text respectively.

Then,

```
import smtplib, MimeWriter, mimetools, base64

message = StringIO.StringIO()
email_msg = MimeWriter.MimeWriter(message)
email_msg.addheader('To', to)
email_msg.addheader('From', sender)
email_msg.addheader('Subject', subject)
email_msg.addheader('MIME-Version', '1.0')

email_msg.startmultipartbody('mixed')

part = email_msg.nextpart()
body = part.startbody('text/plain')
part.flushheaders()
body.write(text)

file_to_attach = '/home/local/user/project/zip_module/csv.zip'
filename = os.path.basename(file_to_attach)
ftype, encoding = 'application/zip', None

part = email_msg.nextpart()
part.addheader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', encoding)
body = part.startbody("%s; name=%s" % (ftype, filename))
mimetools.encode(open(file_to_attach, 'rb'), body, encoding)

email_msg.lastpart()

email_text = message.getvalue()
```

Now send the email like you did using `smtplib`, with `email_text` as `msg`

e.g.

```
smtp = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER, PORT)
smtp.login(USER, PASSWORD)
smtp.sendmail(sender, to, email_text)
smtp.quit()
```

Comment: k i tried above code its showing Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "schedular_runner.py", line 78, in <module>
    part.addheader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', encoding)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/MimeWriter.py", line 105, in addheader
    lines = value.split("\n")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: My bad, please use encoding as 'binary' or 'base64' instead of None declared here ftype, encoding = 'application/zip', None

Comment: thankyou, but actually an email has been sent succesfully but there is no attachement to that mail, i have whether there is file_to_attach path by printing it and i can able to see the zip file which is to be fetched, but it is not attaching to the mail

Answer (score 2):

Try the [`email` package](http://docs.python.org/library/email.mime.html) from the standard library. It lets you construct multipart MIME messages which can contain a `text/plain` part (for the text you want to send) and an `application/zip` part for the ZIP file. You can then serialize the message to a string and send that using `smtplib`.